# Frequent Wifi Drops

Tags: wireless

On My Asus Laptop, I am connected to the internet, and almost every 10 minutes, I get no internet connection while still being connected to WiFi. Any additional information about the problem will be given!

Output of `lspci -vvv`:

```
$ lspci -vvv
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort+ <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: bdw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 49
    Region 0: Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 2: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 52
    Region 0: Memory at b221c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at b2210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 201f
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 45
    Region 0: Memory at b2200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 48
    Region 0: Memory at b2224000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 51
    Region 0: Memory at b2218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-00000fff
    Memory behind bridge: fff00000-000fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: b2100000-b21fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: b2000000-b20fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort+ <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 46
    Region 0: I/O ports at 50b0 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at 50a0 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 5090 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 5080 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Region 5: Memory at b2222000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at b2221000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19ad
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at b2220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 200f
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 47
    Region 0: I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b2104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at b2100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2161
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 50
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
```

Comment: Can you tell us which WiFi card you're using (`lspci -vvv`) and what make/model is your WiFi router?   Also, are you running any other OSs and does it work in them?  Lastly, have you checked your antenna?  Frequently, dropouts are due to a loose or cracked antenna cable.

Comment: Hello! Here's the output!: http://pastebin.com/SRprUJqv

Comment: Please don't pastebin.  It's strongly encouraged to edit your question and put it in there.  That way, relevant information doesn't get lost when the pastebin is deleted.

Comment: Oh, and we also need to know what version of Ubuntu you're running.   If you can call `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`.  And the model number of your laptop.  These all help us to find other reports of the issue.

Comment: So far, it looks like (a) You're using a Broadwell-U chipset, which may have issues with older kernels.  So `uname -a` will tell you that.  And (b) You're using a lesser-known AzureWave 2161 WiFi adapter which is being picked up as a Realtek 8821AE.  Either of these could be your issue.

Comment: It's this laptop https://www.shopmyexchange.com/asus-r-series-15-6-in-intel-core-i5-2-2ghz-6gb-1tb-windows-10-notebook/7418898;jsessionid=38154BB35D5F01D74E9068D01B59DA69.aafes-store1-12

and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Yes, but Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can have any number of kernel versions.  We need you to run `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a` and include that information in the question as well.

Comment: travis@pc:~$ uname -a
Linux pc 4.2.0-34-generic #39~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:38:02 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
travis@pc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
travis@pc:~$

Comment: Ok.  There's something odd with your setup already.  Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't yet have Kernel 4.2.0.  Ubuntu 15.10 does.  You could consider upgrading to 15.10 properly.  Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: travis@pc:~$ cd Applications/lwfinger
bash: cd: Applications/lwfinger: No such file or directory
travis@pc:~$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
The program 'git' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install git
travis@pc:~$ cd rtlwifi_new/
bash: cd: rtlwifi_new/: No such file or directory
travis@pc:~$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
travis@pc:~$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for travis: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for travis: 
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
travis@pc:~$

Comment: Im confused :(?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  You needed to create the Applications/lwfinger directory first, and install git.

Answer (score 1):

**Safe Answer**

*Wait until new drivers are eventually merged into the Ubuntu kernel modules.*  Consider upgrading your Ubuntu installation to 15.10 (or 16.04 later this month).

---

**Alternative Answer**

WiFi cards are cheap and pretty standard these days.  You can always just open up your laptop, pop out the pre-installed PCIe WiFi card, and install one that is compatible with Ubuntu.  (And don't forget to reattach both antennas!)

---

**Unsafe Answer**

Some have said [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256469) that newer versions of the Realtek driver solve these kinds of issues, among others.

** ***Beware, using non-production drivers can cause damage to your hardware.*** **

** ***Proceed at own risk!*** **

** ***You have been warned!!!*** **

Here's a way to get the newer drivers:

First, ensure that the build-essential packages are installed (for gcc, make, etc.), git (to get the external sources) and linux headers:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git linux-headers-`uname -r`-generic
```

Then make a directory and clone ad build the current rtlwifi driver:

```
mkdir -p Applications/lwfinger
cd Applications/lwfinger
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new/
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
```

Then install the driver:

```
sudo mv /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko.save
sudo mv /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192ee/r8192ee.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192ee/r8192ee.ko.save

sudo modprobe -v rtl8821ae
```

To undo these changes:

```
sudo mv /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko.save /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
sudo mv /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192ee/r8192ee.ko.save /lib/modules/`uname -r`-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192ee/r8192ee.ko
```